# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal

Tags: xcode, react-native, push-notification, react-native-onesignal

Trying to integrate `one signal` in my react native app.

I followed all the instructions mentioned in the docs
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup.

The build for the app gets succeeded but I get an error while attaching the app to the device.

Xcode opens a thread with a title `dyld__abort_with_payload`.

Here's the image of it.
[image]

And when I look into the errors. The Errors look like this.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal
  Referenced from: /Users/sakshyaarora/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/357B8E50-B8A6-4F9D-AE06-40DD8004351E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/242BEDF6-76CD-4516-BF58-C86C43F6C4D4/Test.app/Test
  Reason: image not found
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DIR=/Users/sakshyaarora/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld/20F71/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-5.18E182
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/sakshyaarora/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-djshtsdmeowdbaebqzmujevyppyj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Users/sakshyaarora/Sites/projects/Test/Builds/iOS/build/Debug/-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Applica
```

It's been hours since I am trying this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: did you ended up fixing this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I was able to fix this issue but the solution was very weird...that's why I didn't post it in the answer...I'll update the answer in some time maybe it can help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution I got is really very weird and it just came out while trying and was able to resolve this issue for me. So if anyone here is getting the same error can try this.

**Steps**

**Open Xcode** -> **Select your app in the Targets** -> **Go to General Tab** -> **Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content**.

Click on **+** . Search for `OneSignal` in it and add `OneSignal.xcframework`.

[image]

Here comes the weird part.

After `OneSignal.xcframework` is added. Just remove this `OneSignal.xcframework` by selecting and clicking **-**.

Now just build your app again. Your app should run now.

Comment: As I can see, this weird manipulation adds "@executable_path/Frameworks" to the *Linking -> Runpath Search Path*

Comment: Yes, it was correct - after adding paths app starts normally!

Comment: I was able to solve this issue in your way but adding "OneSignalCore" & "OneSignalOutcomes" and keeping it on the framework list as "Embed & Sign". Also, move this pods from OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension to the app main target. More here https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-onesignal/issues/1459

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing the same issue in Flutter or React-Native
Then you should try to create a `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` in the Targets and add this extension in `Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content` section of `Target>General`.

You can follow the following steps:

1. Open `Runner.xcworkspace` from the iOS folder of your project
2. Click on "+" icon to add a Target and search for `Notification Service Extension`

[image]

3. Create a new `Notification Service Extension` for OneSignal, select your team and keep the rest as default.
4. In the next step go to `General Tab > Frameworks,Libraries and Embedded Content` and add "**OneSignalCore.xcframework**", "**OneSignalOutcomes.xcframework**" by clicking the "+" icon and keep it on the framework list as "Embed & Sign", also add the newly created `Notification Service Extension` as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

5. Next Step is to add and remove(yes that's right) the "**OneSignal.xcframework**" (please be careful with the name, this one is just onesignal...), so you have to add `OneSignal.xcframework` in `General Tab > Frameworks,Libraries and Embedded Content` by clicking the "+" icon and then remove it by selecting this list item and clicking the "-" icon.

After doing these steps you can simply clean your project and run it, it should work!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sakshya73 for his helpful response.
After completing the task, I encountered the same error again. However, I managed to resolve it by navigating to the iOS directory and executing

- pod cache clean --all
- pod deintegrate
- pod install

After performing these steps, I attempted to build again, and this time, it was successful.